# How does Rose Tree unfold work (from Origami Programming)

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have been reading the article [*Origami Programming* by Jeremy Gibbons](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~3860418/msc/11_infomtpt/papers/origami-programming_Gibbons.pdf)  and am having trouble figuring out how the `unfoldR` and `unfoldF` functions work for `Rose Trees`.

In the paper the `Rose Tree` type is defined as:

```
data Rose α = Node α (Forest α)
type Forest α = List (Rose α)
```

The `unfoldR` and `unfoldF` functions are mutually recursive and defined as:

```
unfoldR :: (β → α) → (β → List β) → β → Rose α
unfoldR f g x = Node (f x) (unfoldF f g x)

unfoldF :: (β → α) → (β → List β) → β → Forest α
unfoldF f g x = mapL (unfoldR f g) (g x)
```

It looks like that, except in a few small edge cases, these functions will recurse infinitely. How do these two mutually recursive functions terminate?

Comment: It terminates when `unfoldF` returns an empty list, i.e. when `g x` returns an empty list.

Comment: There is no reason why they should terminate. What's important is that they are *productive*. They support pattern matching on the rose tree, in that whenever the node structure is demanded, it's delivered. It may happen not to be the case that on every path through the tree, a node with an empty list of subtrees is eventually found. Infinite growth is possible. Haskell identifies inductive (all paths necessarily finite) and coinductive (some paths possibly infinite) structures: unfolding is the way to generate coinductive structures. How does it work? Ask rather when does it work? On demand.

Comment: Substituting one into the other gives `unfoldR f g x = Node (f x) (mapL (unfoldR f g) (g x))` which reduces `unfoldR` to a regular recursive function, rather than mutually recursive with `unfoldF`. As @user5402 says, when `g x` returns an empty list, `unfoldF` is mapped across an empty list resulting in zero recursive calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### They do not necessarily terminate!

The definitions of `unfoldR` and `unfoldF` form a [**co-inductive**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coinduction) function on the types `Rose` and `Forest` respectively. Co-induction is the dual of structural induction. Co-inductive functions are designed to create infinite data-structures, which will later be consumed via a recursive function.

Due to Haskell's lazy evaluation, we can define and create an infinite mutually recursive `Rose` and `Forest` data structure by applying a function `f :: (β → α)` and `g :: (β → List β)` and an initial "seed value" `x :: β` to either `unfoldR` and `unfoldF`.

We would then consume the infinite data structure with another recursive function `h :: Rose -> γ`

Putting together an undefined example:

```
f :: (β → α)
f = undefined
g :: (β → List β) 
g = undefined
x :: β
x = undefined
h :: Rose -> γ
h = undefined

result :: γ
result = h $ unfoldR f g x
```

Here `result` would be the evaluation of the computation over the infinite structure. But if it's an infinite data structure, how does `h` terminate? *How can* `result` *ever be evaluated?*

Though `unfoldR f g x` will result in an infinite structure, `h` will only search a **finite** subset of the search space and hence `result` can be evaluated.

**Note:** *We can also define `f`, `g` & `x` to create an finite structure, it need not be infinite*

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  This function will almost always be infinite and works with Haskell because it will be evaluated in a lazily and not lock or stack overflow the program.

Out of curiosity, do you know if unfoldR can generate any possible rose tree or can it only generate a subset of possible rose trees?

Comment: @egerhard For a given parameter type `α`, it is *possible*  depending on the definitions of `f`, `h`, and `x` that the Rose Tree generated by `unfoldR f h x` contains within it's branches all possible Rose Trees as subtrees. To be certain of this, a mathematical proof would be in order.

Comment: @recursion.ninja Could you elaborate on the mathematical proof? (Either yourself &/or w/ a reference)